# The attractiveness of the fixed points in system $z \mapsto z + \xi(\frac{1}{2} + i z)$

Tags: dynamical-systems, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

In essence, I need to determine when a number is within this set: $$\Big\{ t : t \in \mathbb{R} \;\wedge\; \Big|1+ i\xi'\big(\frac12 + i t\big)\Big| < 1 \Big\},$$ where $\xi'$ is the first derivative of the Riemann xi function. This is assuming RH so it's just the critical strip.

Is there a way of simplifying this equation into something more manageable? Or is there a better way of determining this altogether?

Comment: Why do you want to look at this ? For $|t|< 1$ then simply plot your function in 
https://www.wolframalpha.com/ For large real $t$:  $i\xi'(1/2+it)$ is Schwartz real and its sign oscillates so about half of  $t$ are in your set. Are you asking for an algorithm to approximate $\xi'$ for large $t$ ? It is the Riemann Siegel formula. Every zero of $\xi(1/2+it)$ for $t$ large enough is an attractive fixed point.

Comment: @reuns Yes, but what exactly is "large enough" in this circumstance? I am trying to determine which points are attractive and which are repulsive given that system.

Comment: Did you mean $t\in \Bbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @reuns Yes, that was an error of me changing one thing while editing and forgetting to change another. Apologies for that. It should be fixed now.

Comment: No, I mean what I wrote there. $|1 + i\xi'(\frac12 + it)| < 1$ is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On $|\Re(s)-1/2|\le 1/4, |\Im(s)|> 1$

$|\zeta(s)|\le 2|s|$ this follows from $\zeta(s)=\frac{s}{s-1}+s\int_1^\infty(\lfloor x\rfloor-x)x^{-s-1}dx$.

$\Gamma(s/2)$ is rapidly decreasing, this is because $|\Gamma(s/2)\prod_{k=0}^{K-1}(s/2+k)|\le \Gamma(1/2+K)$

From there you get some $C=16$ such that $|\xi(s)| \le C /|s|$. This implies by the Cauchy integral formula that $|\xi'(s)|\le 32 C/|s|$.

$\xi(1/2+it)$ is real: this follows from the functional equation that $\Gamma(s/2)\pi^{-s/2}\zeta(s)$ is invariant under $s\to 1-s$ and is complex conjugated under $s\to \overline{s}$, thus $i\xi'(1/2+it)$ is real.

$\xi(1/2+it)$ changes of sign infinitely often (this is a bit less obvious) thus $i\xi'(1/2+it)$ changes of sign infinitely often. Assuming that there are  no double zeros, exactly half of non-trivial zeros $1/2+it, t> 32C$ are attractive fixed points of $s\to s+\xi(s)$. Assuming the RH there are no others in the critical strip.